# Why won't SET method in C++ update attributes inside class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, attributes, set

I want the terminal to show the person's updated name and position but as you can see at the bottom, it won't do that, please help.

**CODE**

```
class Staff : public Person 
{
    protected:

        int employeeId;
        double salary;
        Person pIdentifier;
        MechanicalAppliances mechApp;


    public:

        Staff()
        {
            employeeId = 0;
            salary = 0;
        }

        Staff(Person pId, int eId, double sry, MechanicalAppliances app)
        {
            employeeId = eId;
            salary = sry;
            mechApp = app;
            pIdentifier = pId;
        }

        Staff(Person pId, int eId, double sry)
        {
            employeeId = eId;
            salary = sry;
            pIdentifier = pId;
        }

        void setEmployeeID(int eId)
        {
            employeeId = eId;
        }

        int getEmployeeID()
        {
            return employeeId;
        }

        void setSalary(double sry)
        {
            salary = sry;
        }

        double getSalary()
        {
            return salary;
        }

        std::string toString() 
        {
            std::string id = std::to_string(employeeId);
            std::string sal = std::to_string(salary);

            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "----------------------";
            std::string msg = "\n Employee: ";
            msg = msg + "\n Name: " + Person::nameOfEmployee;
            msg = msg + "\n Position: " + Person::positionOfEmployee;
            msg = msg + "\n Id of Employee: " + id;
            msg = msg + "\n Salary: " + sal;
            msg = msg + "\n In charge of machinery type: " + nameOfMachinery1;
            return msg;
        }

        void print() 
        {
            std::cout << this->toString();
        }

int main() 
{
    Person p1("Miguel Vo", "Floor Manager");
    p1.setNameOfEmployee("Miguel Vo");

    Staff e1(p1, 1, 1000000, mech1);
    e1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

As a result it won't update the attribute on terminal:

Employee:

**Name: no-name**

**Position: no-position**

Id of Employee: 1

Salary: 1000000.000000

In charge of machinery type: Storage Bins

Comment: Important definitions are missing. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Why does `Staff` both inherits from `Person` and includes it as a member? Seem like a wrong design.

Comment: Tangential: You probably don't want to be writing to `std::cout` in the middle of `toString`. Just return a `std::string` and let calling code decide what to do with it. Or write an `operator<<` overload.

Comment: The problem is in the `Person` base class, but you failed to show its code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.